# Objective-C A switch statement inside another switch statement

Tags: objective-c

So I have created a switch statement inside another switch statement for certain sections and rows, quite hard to explain so have a look at the actual code. Anyways I was wondering if such patter should be avoided or if it does not really matter, I am new to stackoverflow as you may have already noticed so I am not entirely sure this question has been asked before.

```
    switch(indexPath.section) {

    case 0: {
        switch ([indexPath row]) {
            case 0: {
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:introductionViewController animated:YES];
                        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
                break;
            }
            case 1: {

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:matterViewController animated:YES];
                    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
                break;
            }

            break;
        }


    case 1: {


        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its gonna be hard to i understand ur problem if u don't show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `switch` statement inside of a `switch` statement is perfectly legal. There's nothing inherently wrong with it, though it may be difficult to follow if there are many cases in either statement. One solution is to make the inner switch statement into a separate function or method. For example, if you have this:

```
switch (a)
{
    case foo:
        switch (b)
        {
            case bar:
                doSomething();
            break;

            case bas:
                doSomethingElse();
            break;
        }
        break;
    case foo2:
        ...whatever
}
```

You could do it like this:

```
void handleFoo (int x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
        case bar:
            doSomething();
        break;

        case bas:
            doSomethingElse();
        break;
    }
}

...
main ()
{
    ...
    switch (a)
    {
        case foo:
            handleFoo(b);
        break;
        case foo2:
           ...whatever;
        break;
    }
}
```